# Nginx basic auth with Cloud Run is not working

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

With same docker image(Cloud registry), it can prompt popup to input username/password in local but it always return `401` in Cloud Run

nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd; 
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
  
  include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Local run:

```
 docker run -d -p 9091:80 asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service/my-service@sha256:b09537845fc8be8db82a7c772dd6b47cf4460cbbd5bc7e209c405be102248619
```

Does GCP Cloud Run support nginx basic auth? or I did wrong somewhere?

Comment: Is the Cloud Run service public?

Comment: The 401 is probably coming from the fact that you don't allow cloud run to be called without authentication (which is the default, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview) and not from your basic authentication.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, it is public:
`Ingress  = "Allow all traffic"`, `Authentication = "Allow unauthenticated invocations"`

FYI, it just not work when I added `auth_basic` in nginx config

Comment: If this is an Nginx issue, look at the Nginx logs for problem details. Post relevant log entries in your question. Enable logging if necessary.

Comment: Could you guide me how to get the nginx log? Because the docker image run on  GCP Cloud Run and I only can view the logs tab and all requests responsed `401` code when I add `auth_basic` to nginx config.

Comment: Again, the same docker image can run on my local machine, it can prompt username/password to the client.
It just has issue when run this image on GCP Cloud Run.